# Post and Comment does not work properly when display with jquery ajax with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working with the post and comment screen, where i have to extract the post from other table and comments related to other that particular post from other table and i am using ajax jquery for that but when changing tab very fastly 
i can say that comment and post is not loading completely sometimes, but when i am using ajax with async:false it works perfectly but the problem is the browser hangs for some seconds. Is there any way i could know that web page loading status so that i can put there progress bar so it doen't seem that the browser getting hang, i have tried, oncomplete, when, then but it does not works, there is multiple ajax functions inside another ajax function because it cannot be retrieved in one ajax call, and html elements is also being appended with jquery  i have given this code as a example, please provide some help, thanks in adbance:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'get_record.php',
    dataType:'json',
    async: false,
    success:function(result){
        var mainDiv = $('#main_outer');

        $.each(result, function(key,value) {
            var box_wrapper = $('<div>').addClass('boxwrapper').appendTo(mainDiv);
        });
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
         $('.loader').show();  
    },
    complete: function(){
         $('.loader').hide(); 
    }  
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will block page load/interaction as long as your code is running. By setting `async: false`, you will freeze the page. Better to use a callback function and fix the tab-changing bug by checking if the tab has changed from your callback before the content is modified.

Comment: Can you please give me a link of an example of how to use callback and thanks for your answer.

Comment: because i have no idea of how to use callback function here and i am stuck at this part. If you can provide some help